# Radiator grid bended due to car crash - How do I know it should be changed?

Tags: radiator

Unfortunately, someone backed into my car and the radiator grid was bent. The car seems to work fine but I am afraid I am missing something. The grid is a bit bent because of the trailer ball that hit it.

How do I know I should change the grid or all the radiator system?

This is the result (sorry about the insects):

[image: Radiator with bent cooling fins]

I have added a photo in the question. No, the radiator is not leaking and the car is not overheating. The only weird thing is that the blue light of the radiator (cold condition) is almost always on in the panel.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the radiator at the very front of the car, then it is likely the air conditioning condenser.  If the air conditioning is still working well, then you are probably OK.

If your car doesn’t have air conditioning, then it may be an inter cooler if your car has a turbocharger.  If the intercooler is leaking slightly, then it can cause subtle issues for the engine.

If it is coolant radiator, then keep an eye out for leaking coolant.

Tell us which car you have and whether it has air con and which engine it has.